# What is wrong with my Triangle area constructor?

Tags: javascript

```
function triangle(sideOne, sideTwo, sideThree)
{
    this.sideOne = sideOne;
    this.sideTwo = sideTwo;
    this.sideThree = sideThree;

    var result = 
    {
        return (this.sideOne + this.sideTwo + this.sideThree)/2;
    };

    this.heronFormula = function()
        {
            return Math.sqrt(result*(result-this.sideOne)*(result-this.sideTwo)*
            (result-this.sideThree));         
        };

}

var newTriangle = new triangle(5,6,7);

console.log(newTriangle.heronFormula());
```

I am trying to find the area of a triangle using heron's formula but I am receiving the error: "Unexpected token this". Does anyone know what that might be?

Comment: No details? I don't like playing find the needle in the codestack.

Comment: Sorry, the description didn't go though. I've added it now.

Comment: If you look at [the formula definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), you see that `result` should be really called `semiperimeter`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = 
    {
        return (this.sideOne + this.sideTwo + this.sideThree)/2;
    };
```

should be

```
var result = (this.sideOne + this.sideTwo + this.sideThree) / 2;
```

The problem is that you have defined the `result` variable inside object notation.

Just assign the value to the result directly. When the `heronFormula` is invoked on the triangle object, the `result` is already in the scope which forms a closure for the `heronFormula` function.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2mxs35p/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
function Triangle(sideOne, sideTwo, sideThree)
{
    this.sideOne = sideOne;
    this.sideTwo = sideTwo;
    this.sideThree = sideThree;

    this.result = (this.sideOne + this.sideTwo + this.sideThree)/2;
}

Triangle.prototype.heronFormula = function() {
   return Math.sqrt(this.result*(this.result-this.sideOne)*(this.result-this.sideTwo)*(this.result-this.sideThree));         
};


var newTriangle = new Triangle(5,6,7);

console.log(newTriangle.heronFormula());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

https://jsfiddle.net/dznatab1/

```
function triangle(sideOne, sideTwo, sideThree)
{
   this.sideOne  = sideOne;
   this.sideTwo  = sideTwo;
   this.sideThree = sideThree;
   var result = (this.sideOne + this.sideTwo + this.sideThree)/2;  

   triangle.prototype.heronFormula  = function(){
     return Math.sqrt(result*(result-sideOne)*(result-sideTwo)*(result-sideThree)); 
   }; 
}
var newTriangle = new triangle(5,6,7);
console.log(newTriangle.heronFormula());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = 
{
    return (this.sideOne + this.sideTwo + this.sideThree)/2;
};
```

should be

```
var result = function() { ... };
```